# После получения аудио и номера, отправлять его в личные сообщения telegram себе

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Помогите с кодом , написал код который пересылает в этот же диалог но от другого айди

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])
def checkbot_voice(message):
    bot.forward_message(chatID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

код для понимания:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document', 'voice','text'])
def handle_document_voice_text(message): 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Задание‌ ‌получено!‌ ‌Введите‌ ‌ваш‌ ‌номер‌ ‌телефона‌ ‌и‌ ‌мы‌ ‌свяжемся‌ ‌с‌ ‌вами‌.‌ ‌')

@bot.message_handler(commands=[ 872515281])
def chat_id(message):
    my_chat_id = int(message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, my_chat_id)
```

Comment: Ииии? В чём проблема-то? С чем помогать?

Comment: Т.к. Вы новичок, не стану закрывать вопрос по этой причине, а просто добавлю это сюда. Надеюсь, Вы прислушаетесь: *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.*

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужно написать код который пересылает сообщение пользователя (пользователь пишет боту),на мой ID(мне в личку ),я написал код выше,но он не работает .Ниже код для понимания.
"@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document', 'voice','text'])
def handle_document_voice_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Задание‌ ‌получено!‌ ‌Введите‌ ‌ваш‌ ‌номер‌ ‌телефона‌ ‌и‌ ‌мы‌ ‌свяжемся‌ ‌с‌ ‌вами‌.‌ ‌')

@bot.message_handler(commands=[ 872515281])
def chat_id(message):
    my_chat_id = int(message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, my_chat_id)"

Comment: Смотрели, почему *не работает*? Как именно он не работает? Просто ничего не присылает или присылает но не то или не туда? Поделитесь своими предположениями о том, где, по-Вашему скрыта ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

используйте [bot.register_next_step_handler](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py) чтобы получить сообщение и далее с ним работать.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document', 'voice','text'])
def handle_document_voice_text(message): 
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Задание‌ ‌получено!‌ ‌Введите‌ ‌ваш‌ ‌номер‌ ‌телефона‌ ‌и‌ ‌мы‌ ‌свяжемся‌ ‌с‌ ‌вами‌.‌ ‌')
   bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, handle_document_voice_text_2)

def handle_document_voice_text_2(message):
    print(message.text)  # текст отправленный на вопрос "введите ваш номер..."
    bot.send_message(123, '{}'.format(message.text)
```

Comment: Ничего не происходит, не отправляет на мой ID((

Comment: вы указали свой id вместо 123?

Comment: Конечно
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document', 'voice','text'])
def handle_document_voice_text(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Задание‌ ‌получено!‌ ‌Введите‌ ‌ваш‌ ‌номер‌ ‌телефона‌ ‌и‌ ‌мы‌ ‌свяжемся‌ ‌с‌ ‌вами‌.‌ ‌')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, handle_document_voice_text_2)

def handle_document_voice_text_2(message):
    print(message.text)
    bot.send_message(   439577128, '{}'.format(message.text))

bot.polling()
может нужно установить библиотеку для регистра?

Comment: вы видите вывод `print` в `handle_document_voice_text_2`? если да, бот может вам написать?

Comment: Он отвечает мне в диалоге с ним,но не пересылает голосовое сообщение)

Comment: в моём примере отправка текста, а не голосового сообщения.

Comment: я исправил на voice но не работает ,текст пересылает да но не на мой id а обратно в чат бот

Comment: приведите строку пересылки.

Comment: bot.send_message(872515281, '{}'.format(message.text)) 
эту?

Comment: ту в которой вы пересылаете `voice`

Comment: bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, handle_document_voice_text_3)
def handle_document_voice_text_3(message):
    print(message.voice)
    bot.send_message(   872515281, '{}'.format(message.voice))

проблема в том что я не могу даже текст файл отправить в другую беседу ,он мне пересылает в этот же диалог с ботом.

Comment: Напишите свой ник в телеграм, в комментариях не удобно

Comment: @bbizon 
872515281 и id если что

Comment: Я заметил что когда я пишу свой id оно работает в этом же диалоге а когда чужой то нет)